# BrowserStack and Azure integration and Run Tests

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, browserstack

This is new topic for me, I am trying to integrate BrowserStack with Azure DevOps pipelines.

I have followed all steps mention in the documentation by Browserstack
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/azure-pipelines#configuring-build-pipeline

But after I run the automation on Azure it does not trigger anything on
Browserstack.com (Browserstack Dashboard).

I do not have that much knowledge about Azure. Any help is really appreciated

Pipeline configuration :-

[image]

After Run:-
[image]

Project is based on TestNG selenium Java

Answer (score 2):

There should be a step in between Configuration Setup and Stop Local, where you want to run your selenium test script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you confirm the test are running on the pipeline any logs will help us to investigate this further. Also, you run a sample test
https://github.com/browserstack/testng-browserstack and visit Dashboard
https://automate.browserstack.com/dashboard/v2